# Are there duels between "good" characters in Game of Thrones?

Tags: game-of-thrones, a-song-of-ice-and-fire

I'm well aware that no character can be considered fully good or evil in the Game of Thrones universe.

However, the show tends to make us hate or love some characters based on the morality or dishonor in their acts. At least that's my impression.

This good or evil "tag" on every character can change during the story, like with Jaime (and I hope with Sansa in the future). But it's rather stable in time.

So let's call a "good" character one that has been acting morally or with honor at least for some time.

Now **are there exemples of duels where two "good" characters had to fight each other**? The emotional effect would be particularly interesting. The only cases I can think of are:

- Brienne vs the Hound for Arya's protection
- Brienne vs Loras in Renly's honor
- Beric vs the Hound as noted by TLP in comments.

Interestingly,

> nobody *really* died in these cases.

Examples from books are welcome!

Comment: Precedence of what? Just the duels? Also, your definition of "good" may need clarification. For example, does the duel between Lord Beric and the Hound count? Both were innocent, and both did good.

Comment: Essentially, what you're asking for is a list of all of the duels ever taken in tourneys.

Comment: Also defining "good" and "bad", even if you try to mix in honour, is going to be extremely difficult in the ASOIAF universe. For example, Ned and Jamie's "duel" in King's Landing could fit here, since both were acting on what they believed was "right". Even though Jamie at that point was associated with "bad" and Ned was "good".

Comment: Bronn vs Ser Vardis at Tyrion's first trial by combat? That's one where someone dies; both were doing something good (standing up for the underdog vs doing a knight's duty standing up for his lady), albeit with an understandable splash of self interest (wanting Lannister gold vs wanting favour with Lady Arryn). Maybe Jon vs Halfhand is another where someone died, but maybe that doesn't count because one party was fighting to lose. I'm also tempted to suggest Brienne vs the bear...

Comment: Define "good"..

Comment: Young Ned vs Arthur Dayne.